# Gather a wide data frame into narrow but expand to create interim rows

Tags: r

I have a data frame with two date/time columns:

```
            BeginTime             EndTime      Value
-----------------------------------------------------
1 2019-01-03 13:45:00     2019-01-03 17:30:00    41
2 2019-01-03 13:30:00     2019-01-03 14:30:00    20
3 2019-01-03 16:45:00     2019-01-03 19:00:00    23
```

That I need to transform into this:

```
       Time               Value
--------------------------------
 1 2019-01-03 13:45:00      41
 2 2019-01-03 14:00:00      41
 3 2019-01-03 14:15:00      41
 4 2019-01-03 14:30:00      41
 5 2019-01-03 14:45:00      41
 6 2019-01-03 15:00:00      41
 7 2019-01-03 15:15:00      41
 8 2019-01-03 13:30:00      20
 9 2019-01-03 13:45:00      20
10 2019-01-03 14:00:00      20
11 2019-01-03 14:15:00      20
12 2019-01-03 16:45:00      23
```

But not sure how to do that. Any suggestions?

Code to create testdf

```
testdf <- data.frame(c("2019-01-03 13:45:00", "2019-01-03 13:30:00", "2019-01-03 16:45:00"), 
                 c("2019-01-03 15:30:00", "2019-01-03 14:30:00", "2019-01-03 17:00:00"), 
                 c(41,20,23))
colnames(testdf) <-c("BeginTime", "EndTime", "Value")
testdf$BeginTime <- as.POSIXct(testdf$BeginTime)
testdf$EndTime <- as.POSIXct(testdf$EndTime)
```

(I know there's probably a way to create the columns as POSIXct initially but this works)

Comment: Why does value 41 not end at `17:30`? Same with others not reach end times?

Comment: @Parfait because the example shown is different than the reproducible example used...

Comment: Actually, because it's because I'm looking for all 15-minute blocks that fall between the two dates. So the block starting at 17:30 doesn't fall within the boundaries. But I can work with the solution you provided @Sotos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `seq` between the two columns and create a list with complete 15 minute intervals for each `Beginning - End`and then use `rep` based on their length to get the value, i.e.

```
l1 <- Map(function(x, y)seq(x, y, by = '15 mins'), testdf$BeginTime, testdf$EndTime)

data.frame(Time = do.call(c, l1), value = rep(testdf$Value, lengths(l1)))
```

which gives,

> ```
>                   Time value
> 1  2019-01-03 13:45:00    41
> 2  2019-01-03 14:00:00    41
> 3  2019-01-03 14:15:00    41
> 4  2019-01-03 14:30:00    41
> 5  2019-01-03 14:45:00    41
> 6  2019-01-03 15:00:00    41
> 7  2019-01-03 15:15:00    41
> 8  2019-01-03 15:30:00    41
> 9  2019-01-03 13:30:00    20
> 10 2019-01-03 13:45:00    20
> 11 2019-01-03 14:00:00    20
> 12 2019-01-03 14:15:00    20
> 13 2019-01-03 14:30:00    20
> 14 2019-01-03 16:45:00    23
> 15 2019-01-03 17:00:00    23
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Using the tidyverse

```r
testdf <- data.frame(c("2019-01-03 13:45:00", "2019-01-03 13:30:00", "2019-01-03 16:45:00"), 
                     c("2019-01-03 15:30:00", "2019-01-03 14:30:00", "2019-01-03 17:00:00"), 
                     c(41,20,23))
colnames(testdf) <-c("BeginTime", "EndTime", "Value")
testdf$BeginTime <- as.POSIXct(testdf$BeginTime)
testdf$EndTime <- as.POSIXct(testdf$EndTime)

library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date
testdf %>%
  mutate(periods = map2(BeginTime,EndTime,seq,by = '15 mins')) %>% 
  unnest(periods)
#> # A tibble: 15 x 4
#>    BeginTime           EndTime             Value periods            
#>    <dttm>              <dttm>              <dbl> <dttm>             
#>  1 2019-01-03 13:45:00 2019-01-03 15:30:00    41 2019-01-03 13:45:00
#>  2 2019-01-03 13:45:00 2019-01-03 15:30:00    41 2019-01-03 14:00:00
#>  3 2019-01-03 13:45:00 2019-01-03 15:30:00    41 2019-01-03 14:15:00
#>  4 2019-01-03 13:45:00 2019-01-03 15:30:00    41 2019-01-03 14:30:00
#>  5 2019-01-03 13:45:00 2019-01-03 15:30:00    41 2019-01-03 14:45:00
#>  6 2019-01-03 13:45:00 2019-01-03 15:30:00    41 2019-01-03 15:00:00
#>  7 2019-01-03 13:45:00 2019-01-03 15:30:00    41 2019-01-03 15:15:00
#>  8 2019-01-03 13:45:00 2019-01-03 15:30:00    41 2019-01-03 15:30:00
#>  9 2019-01-03 13:30:00 2019-01-03 14:30:00    20 2019-01-03 13:30:00
#> 10 2019-01-03 13:30:00 2019-01-03 14:30:00    20 2019-01-03 13:45:00
#> 11 2019-01-03 13:30:00 2019-01-03 14:30:00    20 2019-01-03 14:00:00
#> 12 2019-01-03 13:30:00 2019-01-03 14:30:00    20 2019-01-03 14:15:00
#> 13 2019-01-03 13:30:00 2019-01-03 14:30:00    20 2019-01-03 14:30:00
#> 14 2019-01-03 16:45:00 2019-01-03 17:00:00    23 2019-01-03 16:45:00
#> 15 2019-01-03 16:45:00 2019-01-03 17:00:00    23 2019-01-03 17:00:00
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>